# Is there a way to disable logout upon pressing the power button?

Tags: keyboard, sleep-wake

So I've found that on 2020 MacBooks, pressing the power button instantly brings up the login screen. I find this annoying because occasionally I want to use the power button for something, such as putting the computer to sleep, without logging out.

Is there a way to disable this functionality of the power button?

Answer (score 1):

Just in case you will not find the solution, "putting computer to sleep" is nicely done with **Settings** > **Desktop & Screen Saver** > **Screen Saver** > **Hot Corners**.

To trigger the sleep screen you just do a slide gesture of the cursor into the preferred display corner, left down in my case.

Comment: Not strictly an answer to the question, but this does help! It's a good workaround if the power button functionality can't be messed with at all.